# C++ postgis prepared statement failing, invalid geometry

Tags: c++, geometry, prepared-statement, postgis, libpqxx

I'm using libpqxx and a prepared statements, when I try to insert programmatically it fails with an error "Invalid geometry", but I can do the same insert via sql prompt.. Am I missing something? I tried to escape the ' in the prepare statement call but same error

```
con.prepare("chat_insert", "INSERT INTO chat values (nextval('chat_seq'), $1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT($2 $3)', 4326), $4)");
worker.prepared("chat_insert")(chatid)(lon)(lat)(msg).exec();
worker.commit();
```

I also tried

```
con.prepare("chat_insert", "INSERT INTO chat values (nextval('chat_seq'), $1, ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT($2 $3)\', 4326), $4)");
```

Output:

```
Chat id: chat:user:128946234
Lat: 14.6049
Lon: 121.033
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(" <-- parse error at position 6 within geometry
```

If I go into the sql prompt I can run this and it'll insert

```
insert into chat values (nextval('chat_seq'), 'chat:user:128946234', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(121.033 14.6049)', 4326), 'This is a test msg....');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to parse a WKT string of `POINT($2 $3)` which has dollar signs in it. These are not parameters in this context, since WKT is a string.

Use a function that accepts numeric parameters, such as `ST_MakePoint(x, y)`:

```
con.prepare("chat_insert", "INSERT INTO chat (chatid, geom, msg) "
            "VALUES ($1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($2, $3), 4326), $4)");
```

Note that I've listed the columns to insert after `chat`, which is considered a best practice.